# Changing slide based on URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, revolution-slider

I am using Revolution Slider plugin for 1 slider that has 3 slides.
That plugin providesa easy way to call specific slide like this (where 16 is slider ID and 2 is number of slide that needs to be displayed). 
Per their documentation this is how it is done:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('rev_slider_16').scrollIntoView(); revapi16.revshowslide('2'); return false;">Link Text</a>
```

I am using anchors on my page, and depending on anchor clicked, i want to display different slide.
I started like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if(window.location.href === "http://website.com/about/#first"){
        document.getElementById('rev_slider_16').scrollIntoView(); revapi16.revshowslide('1');
    }
    else if(window.location.href === "http://website.com/about/#second"){
        document.getElementById('rev_slider_16').scrollIntoView(); revapi16.revshowslide('2');    
    }
    else if(window.location.href === "http://website.com/about/#last"){
        document.getElementById('rev_slider_16').scrollIntoView(); revapi16.revshowslide('3');
    }
});
```

but i am getting "Cannot read property 'revshowslide' of undefined" error...
I am newbie so i really apologize for stupid question...

**Update:**

On this page i also have 3 tabs and i used similiar approach to show different sliders - and this one works - as bellow.

```
    $('.tabs-wrapper ul li:first-child a').click(function() {
      document.getElementById('rev_slider_16').scrollIntoView(); revapi16.revshowslide('1');
    });
    $('.tabs-wrapper ul li:nth-child(2) a').click(function() {
      document.getElementById('rev_slider_16').scrollIntoView(); revapi16.revshowslide('2');
    });
    $('.tabs-wrapper ul li:last-child a').click(function() {
      document.getElementById('rev_slider_16').scrollIntoView(); revapi16.revshowslide('3');
    });
```

So, basically, i also need to be able to show different slide based on anchor in URL.

Comment: Where do you define `revapi16`? And you could use `window.location.hash`, this would be more easy ...

Comment: the revapi16 object is not definied (at least in this scope). Check out if there is any asynchronous behaviour at the places you set revapi16.

Comment: @eisbehr this is not the problem. revapi16 hasnt been set yet so it doesnt matter wheter or not revshowslide is set or not

Comment: Sorry, just copied the wrong name, meant `revapi16`. ;)

Comment: I thinck you have used an API that not refrence in HTML code. if this is true, I suggest look at to this [link](https://www.themepunch.com/faq/how-to-setup-a-revapi-variable-to-use-the-sliders-api/)

Comment: @mahmoodkabi, it is in documentation - https://www.themepunch.com/faq/link-particular-slider-individual-slide/ (at the bottom)

Comment: @Vabilux, I saw this link. I think you have to define a variable like this: var revapi = jQuery('.tp-banner').show().revolution({}). The variable revapi equlas to revapi16

Comment: @mahmoodkabi, the slider already works properly which means it is properly defined. Only thing not working is when i try to change the slide number based on URL